# SublimeAStyleFormatter Not formattting java,c++ in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext3, formatter

[image]

SublimeAStyleFormatter not formatting any files both the buttons are showing disabled . It is not showing its commands in command palette as well. please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through the issues on the plugin's [Github repo](https://github.com/timonwong/SublimeAStyleFormatter/issues), it looks like the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64) is required for the plugin to work. You can download it [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26999).